# Change dropdown into searchable dropdown in angular js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

html code

```html
<div style="position: absolute" class="container-fluid typeahead-demo" ng-controller="TypeaheadCtrl">
  <input type="text" ng-model="customSelected" placeholder="Custom template" uib-typeahead="state as state.name for state in states | filter:{name:$viewValue}" class="form-control" typeahead-show-hint="true" typeahead-min-length="0">
  <select ng-model="selected_person" ng-options="person.name for person in states | filter: customSelected">
    <option value="">Choose a Name</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

angularjs code

```js
var treectrl = angular.module('mapsApp', []);

treectrl = treectrl.controller('TypeaheadCtrl', function ($scope) {
  $scope.states = [
    {
      name: "Alabama",
      child: ["Alabama1child", "Alabama2child", "Alabama3child"]
    }, 
    {
      name: "Alaska",
      child: ["Alaska1child", "Alaska2child"]
    }
  ];
});
```

this is my code and now i don't want to use input `type="text"`
just want to make dropdown searchable top of dropdown use as a search when click its open with searched word

Comment: So if you search "Ala" then the dropdown should show "Alabama" and "Alaska"?

Comment: yes but i don't want to use input tag  this is working with input tag

Comment: Explain a little more then please. How would you search?

Comment: https://axelzarate.wordpress.com/2014/07/31/custom-dropdown-autocomplete-with-angularjs/

Comment: want to same type of dropdown  search bar in dropdown list

Comment: Try angular materials auto complete. When nothing is entered it'll show everything. Then it'll sort based on what you type.

Comment: https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/autocomplete

Comment: ok but is there any way without angularjs materials

Comment: There are a lot of ways - such as [select2](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select2). Do you mean that you want to write something like this by yourself?

Comment: can anyone hrlp me to change ma current code to required